# let users know results don't match filters

Tags: filter, search-results, messages, faceted-search

We have a page where the users can select filters and then click search to see results.

In the time between the user changing the filters and clicking search, should I indicate the the result don't match the filters?

If so, how?

- just display a message?
- obscure stale results with overlay and display a message?
- hide stale results and display a message?
- something else?

Comment: Is there a reason the user has to click 'search', as opposed to filtering the view in real time as the user applies filters? Also, what's the behavior if the underlying data changes *after* the user views results? This could inform your behavior in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Giving feedback is a definitely a good practice and keeping your audience engaged is even better. You can use many solutions from the bare bone message with an animated icon to a callout in a modal window.

A few things to keep in mind:

- How many searches do you expect your users to make?
- Consider the average loading time
- Keep in mind traffic spikes

You probably won't need much if the results are displayed within a second but if it takes significantly more (booking plane tickets and the likes), then improve the UX by providing your users with some more substantial content: things to do or read.

Take a look at [Response-times-3-important-limits](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/) on J.Nielsen's blog.

As an example, one of the best solution I've seen recently to capture users attention while waiting is at [www.hipmunk.com](http://www.hipmunk.com) but I'm sure there are many other great solutions in the booking industry.

[image]

More in-depth stats at [http://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/) - 2011

**EDIT:** Searching a bit returned some solid research paper on *tolerable waiting time*: http://cba.unl.edu/research/articles/548/download.pdf

---

Disclaimer: I'm providing these links as examples and I am not affiliate with Hipmunk nor with Kiss Metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could use a form of faceted search that would already be able to indicate the number of results. Example:

```
Search Term: Shoes (20 results)

Filter by Color:
Red (5)
Blue (10)
Green (5)
Yellow (0)
```